# Does Apache's "LogLevel" Affect only Error Pages, or Access Logs too?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging

My Apache access_log is only showing a handful of requests. I want to see all hits to the server in the logs. I'm confused about the "LogLevel" directive. Do the various levels (error, warn etc) apply only to the error logs, or to the raw access logs as well? Should I change "LogLevel" to "info" to see all requests?

Edit: I'm running CentOS.

Comment: The directive affects only error logs. Why do you think you don't see all requests in access log?

Comment: @Chris I manually access my site and make sure it hits the server (no caching etc). I don't see my IP anywhere in the logs for the past several days...I don't see any "GET" requests for URLs either. In fact, my access_log is very sparse with hardly only 4 or 5 entries per hour!